# Keeping track of user usage on a Winform application

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms

We have a Winform application that requires user to login using their username and password. The software is free but support is not. The support fee will be based on the number of full time equivalent users so we basically need to track how many hours the software is used per month. The software is written using VS 2010 and the backend is on MS SQL 2008

At the moment, we have a table as below:

```
>CREATE TABLE [UserUsages](
>   [GUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
>   [Source] [varchar](50) NOT NULL, -- Name of the software/front end
>   [WksName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL, -- Name of the workstation 
>   [WksIP] [varchar](50) NOT NULL, -- IP of the workstation
>   [UserGUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL, -- UID of the User who logged in 
>   [TimeIn] [datetime] NOT NULL, -- Time the user logged in
>   [TimOut] [datetime] NOT NULL, -- Time the user logged out
>CONSTRAINT [pk_Usages_GUID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
>([GUID] ASC)
>) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Whenever a user logs in, we create a new record on this table and save the time to the TimeIn column. When user logs out, we update the TimeOut column.

The problem with this approach is if somehow user decided to end task using Windows Task Manager or the system crashed and required a cold reboot then the TimeOut is not updated.

Is there any better way do do it? And also in term of the table structure, is there anything we can do to make it works better?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could just update the TimeOut record with the current time once a minute while the user is logged in ... this way you would have approximate "log out" time even when the system crashes

Comment: Thank you we are already updating the field every 5 minutes. I forgot to mention that in my op. Other from this solution, is there any better way?